Vespertide affairs

Solve on Penpa+
Across
4. Gives 7 down to clumsy doofus from behind (4)
8. Electronic automaton makes comeback in future (2,2)
10. They used to fly by a city with many skyscrapers (6)
11. Militant group has kidnapped old lady (5)
12. Summarize William Spooner's greatest performance in the genre of hip hop (5)
14. Unlocks old prison cells at last (5)
16. 27 down native maybe lacks right to see you (2-2)
18. Back underway after cutting loose couple of goons (3)
20. Forest-dweller character from Germanic folklore that's short and a bit kooky (3)
22. Shipped bouquet delivered (4)
24. Oddly, a squad beat City (5)
26. Prehistoric predator cut short Kay's voyage (4)
28. Seize usurper initially refusing to participate in uprising (3)
30. They invaded many countries during Crusades (3, abbr.)
32. Accompanied by woman whose name is the same backwards and forwards, the first of men (4)
34. Was I Zulu...? Wrong, a different South African! (5)
35. Automobile lover no longer consumed by endless desire (5)
37. Country described by journalists in 31 days (5)
38. Image that's a sign of victory associated with gaming company disassociating itself from independent origin (6)
39. Green Day finally locked in prison (4)
40. Drive away from Peter's brother yet another time (4)
Down
1. They deliver prostitutes for the nouveau riche (8)
2. Soldier whose gear must be packed with standard piece of ammunition (4)
3. Certain French artist who depicted water lilies in paintings without frame? (3)
5. A corn kernel dropped, leading to 7 down (5)
6. Father in Quebec, or the one coming immediately before? (4)
7. Astound a little hound in pound (5)
8. Italian dish cut in halves, served in wrong order? That's something a Spaniard might eat (5)
9. Prohibit East Coast rapper adopting a cuckoo (7)
13. Bubbly and caviar without limit? I cannot take part (4)
15. Vespertide uniform (4)
17. Crew aboard makes everyone wear crouchless bottoms in vessels (8)
19. Scientist abandons Germany; gains success elsewhere (3,4)
21. Area serving as centre of sign resembling big cat's tongue (3)
23. Flip a rock that's massive (4)
25. A sticky situation on Twitter as man leaves Dutch side (4)
27. Russian city in outskirts of Kamchatka, largely eccentric (5)
28. Hot tea consumed here? (5)
29. Lead-up to election: Someone like Joe Biden once comes up, resulting in annoyance (5)
31. Either of two men who moonwalked in the style of Jackson's latest (4)
33. Like a piano, when reading music quickly (4, abbr.)
36. Motor vehicle is prettier after rims are removed (3)

Completed grid:

 

Across clues:

 4. Gives 7 down to clumsy doofus from behind (4) - ZAPS - SPAZ<
 8. Electronic automaton makes comeback in future (2,2) - TO BE - (E- + BOT)<
 10. They used to fly by a city with many skyscrapers (6) - PANAMA - PAN AM + A
 11. Militant group has kidnapped old lady (5) - HAMAS - HA(MA)S
 12. Summarize William Spooner's greatest performance in the genre of hip hop (5) - RECAP - "key rap"
 14. Unlocks old prison cells at last (5) - OPENS - O + PEN + _S
 16. 27 down native maybe lacks right to see you (2-2) - TA-TA - TATA(-r)
 18. Back underway after cutting loose couple of goons (3) - AFT - AF(-oo)T
 20. Forest-dweller character from Germanic folklore that's short and a bit kooky (3) - ELK - EL(-f) + K
 22. Shipped bouquet delivered (4) - SENT - ~scent
 24. Oddly, a squad beat City (5) - AQABA - AsQuAdBeAt
 26. Prehistoric predator cut short Kay's voyage (4) - TREK - TRE(-x) + K
 28. Seize usurper initially refusing to participate in uprising (3) - COP - CO(-u_)P
 30. They invaded many countries during Crusades (3, abbr.) - USA - crUSAdes
 32. Accompanied by woman whose name is the same backwards and forwards, the first of men (4) - ADAM - ADA + M_ &lit!
 34. Was I Zulu...? Wrong, a different South African! (5) - SWAZI - WASIZ*
 35. Automobile lover no longer consumed by endless desire (5) - LEXUS - L(EX)US(-t)
 37. Country described by journalists in 31 days (5) - JAPAN - J(AP)AN
 38. Image that's a sign of victory associated with gaming company disassociating itself from independent origin (6) - AVATAR - A + V + ATAR(-i)
 39. Green Day finally locked in prison (4) - CYAN - C(_Y)AN
 40. Drive away from Peter's brother yet another time (4) - ANEW - AN(-dr)EW

Down clues:

 1. They deliver prostitutes for the nouveau riche (8) - UPSTARTS - UPS + TARTS
 2. Soldier whose gear must be packed with standard piece of ammunition (4) - PARA - PAR + A_
 3. Certain French artist who depicted water lilies in paintings without frame? (3) - ONE - (-m)ONE(-t)
 5. A corn kernel dropped, leading to 7 down (5) - AMAZE - A + MA(-i)ZE
 6. Father in Quebec, or the one coming immediately before? (4) - PAPA ddef (Papa comes immediately before Quebec in the NATO phonetic alphabet)
 7. Astound a little hound in pound (5) - SHOCK - S(H_)OCK
 8. Italian dish cut in halves, served in wrong order? That's something a Spaniard might eat (5) - TAPAS - PAS<->TA
 9. Prohibit East Coast rapper adopting a cuckoo (7) - BANANAS - BAN (A) NAS
 13. Bubbly and caviar without limit? I cannot take part (4) - CAVA - CAV(-i)A(-r)
 15. Vespertide | uniform (4) - EVEN ddef
 17. Crew aboard makes everyone wear crouchless bottoms in vessels (8) - STEAMERS - _S (TEAM) _E _R _S
 19. Scientist abandons Germany; gains success elsewhere (3,4) - FAR AWAY - FARA(-d)(W)AY
 21. Area serving as centre of sign resembling big cat's tongue (3) - LAO - L(e->A)O
 23. Flip a rock that's massive (4) - MEGA - (A + GEM)<
 25. A sticky situation on Twitter as man leaves Dutch side (4) - AJAX - A JA(-m) X
 27. Russian city in outskirts of Kamchatka, largely eccentric (5) - KAZAN - K_A + ZAN(-y)
 28. Hot tea consumed here? (5) - CHINA ddef &lit! (or, as Jafe pointed out, this can also be parsed as CH(IN)A &lit)
 29. Lead-up to election: Someone like Joe Biden once comes up, resulting in annoyance (5) - PEEVE - (E_ VEEP)<
 31. Either of two men who moonwalked in the style of Jackson's latest (4) - ALAN (Bean and Shepard) - A LA + _N
 33. Like a piano, when reading music quickly (4, abbr.) - ASAP - AS + A + P
 36. Motor vehicle is prettier after rims are removed (3) - UTE - (-c)UTE(-r)


Nice work! Believe it or not I actually had different wordplay in mind for 28d, although I see how yours works and wish I'd thought of it :P

ah, I see what you were going for now. I'll add it in

A phenomenal crossword as always @Jafe - really like the use of "tongue" in 21D, and as much as I prefer the name "Twitter", it certainly has more usage in cryptics now! How did you get "AP" in 37A?

@samm82 ap is the associated press. I probably should've explained that when I was writing up the answer but sometimes the line between what to link to and what not to link to is blurry :) I'll edit to clarify

Agreed! Thanks :D
